# How do I make my Xamarin iOS app compatible with 3rd party keyboards like SwiftKey?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm building an app in Xamarin Forms with iOS support, when I deploy to my device my typical SwiftKey keyboard is replaced with the stock iOS one.

This is only in my Xamarin app, my SwiftKey keyboard returns in other apps.
I'm using SDK version 11.0

Any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So third party keyboards are compatible, however any page with a password field will revert back to the native iOS keyboard.